# $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg with custom message is failing

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm applying the code from here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/config/loadingMessageTextVisible.html

Which allows you to add a custom message to your Jquery Mobile loader.

My code is the following:

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("a", "Loading New Chatom");
```

The problem is, this is assigning the CSS Class of **ui-loader-default** and not **ui-loader-verbose** which is needed to show correctly.

When I change my code to

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("a", "Loading New Chatom", true);
```

It displays just fine.  The true removes the animated loader, which is not what I want.  Seems this might be a bug?

*My project is done in coffeescript... though I doubt that's the issue at all.*

Answer (score 9):

This is behaving as designed. In 1.1 you need to set `$.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible = true` to show text in the loader:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible = true;
});
```

The documentation definitely needs to be improved on this feature. The page that describes the new loader options in detail was really just a test area, not a proper documentation page (that's why it's kind of hard to find).

Comment: Thanks Jake, looks like it's not a bug but there is another option to set: http://jsfiddle.net/bJsUG/4/ Here are also the docs on this: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Comment: I wrote that page :)  https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/commit/92da39dfa6fba5b81aee7ac152246cd940dcf136

Comment: It looks like the source ORs that value against what is passed in as a parameter.  So you should be able to pass a 3rd param and set loadingMessageTextVisible, but it didn't work.  Agreed documentation needs updating.

Comment: If you bind to the `mobileinit` event as shown above, your setting will override the default.  This is standard practice for configuring global options in jQM -- [see here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html).

Answer (score 0):

After further testing, I've found the engine checks a value of:

```
 $.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible
```

Which is checked and overwritten in the code.

It's a dirty fix, but setting it to `true` right before the call worked.

Answer (score 0):

put this part of code :

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
$.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible = true;
});
```

AFTER the Jquery.js include
AND BEFORE the jquery mobile include.

Crazy but works fine for us.
(JQM RC1)